# Loop Through List in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a json file 'data' which is a list of dictionaries. One of the keys in every dictionary is 'title' whose value is a a list of titles. How do I display just the first 'title' in this list for every dictionary? The json is as follows:

```
[{'title':['title1','title2,..],'other data':'xyz',...,}...{'title n':['title n1','title n2,..],'other data n1':'xyz n2',...,}
```

This is my views.py:

```
def bill_status(request):
  data = Status.objects.all()
  context = {'data':data}
  return render(request,'billstatus.html',context)
```

In my template I am rendering this as:

```
{% for datum in data %}
<h3>{{datum.title}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the output in html is the entire list for every dictionary:

```
['title1','title2,..]
```

How do I just output 'title1' rather than the entire list?

Comment: Did any of the below answers helped you? If yes, please accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{ datum.title.0 }} would do the trick for you.

Example:-

```
dat = [{'title':['t1','t2']}, {'title':['t3','t4']}];
```

In template

```
 {% for dict in dat %}
     {{dict.title.0}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Output

```
t1 t3
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I just realized I defined the field as a char field in Postgres so I’m getting a ‘{‘ as a result. I guess I need to redefine the model and use arrays?

Answer (score 1):

That would be `<h3>{{ datum.title.0 }}</h3>` to get the first item (`0`) of the list.

You may read more in the docs about the [Django Template Language variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables).